# jQuery ajax call to proxy... Only works the first time

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm doing a few cross-domain Ajax calls, using a local proxy script I wrote in PHP.  The Javascript code for the Ajax calls (a simplified version) is below:

```
<script src="jquery/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

<script language="Javascript">
function link1 ()
{
    $.ajax ({url:"proxy.php", data:{url:"http://www.microsoft.com/"}})
        .done (function (h) { $("#ResponseBody").html(h); })
        .fail (function () { alert ("Ajax failed..."); });
}
function link2 ()
{
    $.ajax ({url:"proxy.php", data:{url:"http://www.yahoo.com/"}})
        .done (function (h) { $("#ResponseBody").html(h); })
        .fail (function () { alert ("Ajax failed..."); });
}
</script>

<a href="javascript:link1();">link 1</a><br>
<a href="javascript:link2();">link 2</a><br>

<div id="ResponseBody"></div>
```

So, it's pretty simple in this example.  I have two functions, each of which performs an Ajax query to my proxy script, passing it a different remote URL.  And you can click on either of the links to call one of those functions.  No matter which one I click on, it works the first time.  But the second time I click on a link (either the same link or the other one), it fails.

I did try removing the code in the .done handlers that displays the Ajax result, and suddenly it started working, although not displaying the result defeats the purpose of doing the Ajax query.  I also tried replacing the references to the proxy script with references to two different plain HTML files on my server, and it worked fine.

Does anyone have any idea why these queries would only work the first time, and not after that?

Comment: Are you able to use developer tools in your browser to see your ajax requests?

Comment: What do you mean by "fail"? Does it alert "Ajax failed.." or does it simply not fetch new data?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear, yes it alerts "Ajax failed" on the second Ajax request that is clicked on.  So in other words, it's calling the .fail handler.  Also, I tried viewing it in Firebug and the first request looks perfect.  Second request doesn't even go out at all, so it doesn't show up in Firebug at all.

Comment: I also put in an alert just to make sure that the link1() and link2() functions are getting called, and sure enough, they are.  I thought that maybe it's caching the results because I'm calling proxy.php in both cases, just with different parameters.  So, I made a copy of proxy.php called proxy2.php and referenced that in the link2() function.  The same thing happened.  No matter which one I click on first, the second one fails with the alert "Ajax failed"...

Comment: Anyone have any idea on this?  I'm completely stumped...